# Spring boot : java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jms

Getting below error while running spring boot application :

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract isAutoStartup()Z of interface org.springframework.context.SmartLifecycle.
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.lambda$startBeans$0(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:144) ~[spring-context-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883) ~[spring-context-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.0.12.RELEASE.jar:5.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) ~[spring-boot-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242) ~[spring-boot-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230) ~[spring-boot-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
```

Comment: What version of the `spring-jms` jar do you have on the class path?

Answer (score 0):

Since your class implements SmartLifecycle interface you need to define all the methods of SmartLifecycle within your class.

Refer Method Summary in this link :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

For me worked in IntelliJ settings in Build, Executions, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven  -> Importing to set Generated sources folders as 'Don't detect'